# how to resolve windows batch file error with token processing?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

') was unexpected at this time.

This above error is seen when i run the below batch file :-

how do i fix this error

```
hostname > tmpFile 
set /p primary= < tmpFile 

pdls -c ser -a primary-host ids_ccm | for /f "tokens=3" %a in ('findstr :') do @echo %a > tmpFile1

set /p previous_primary= < tmpFile1

if "%previous_primary%"=="" pdset -c ser -x"-primary-host %primary% ids_ccm 

else pdset -c ser -x"-primary-host %primary% -previous-primary-host %previous_primary%" ids_ccm
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a batch file, `metavariables` such as the `%a` in your `for` statement must be `%%a`. `%a` is only correct when executing the command directly from the prompt. The syntax for `if/else` is `if value op value (commandstrue) else (commandsfalse)` where `op` is a comparison-operator, the first `(` must be on the same physical line as the `if`, and `) else (` must be on the same physical line. There may be any number of physical lines between `(` and `)`.

Comment: The MS terminology for `%a`, `%%a`, etc is _replaceable parameters_.  [_Metavariables_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metavariable) have a different meaning...